# Firebase registering new users when it should decline them

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm currently working on an android app project and I'm registering new accounts using firebase. I've successfully created a connection and I've managed to register accounts.

When I enter a new users, email,password and a checkbox, and don't check the t&c's checkbox, it comes with a message "Could not register. Please Try Again" However it actually registers them in the firebase auth.

```
//if validation is ok, show progress bar
progressDialog.setMessage("Register User...");
progressDialog.show();

firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
        .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task)
            {
                if(task.isSuccessful() && checkBox.isChecked())
                {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Registered Sucessfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if(!task.isSuccessful())
                {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Could Not Register. Please Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be checking that the checkbox is checked before creating the user.

All of the code placed in the `onComplete` method will run after the user has been registered (or not if there was an error with Firebase). So you are checking that they've checked the T&Cs after they've most likely been registered.

Have an `if (checkBox.isChecked())` check and then within that if-statement, put your code to show the progress dialog and create the user. You can then also change your `onComplete` method to only check

```
if (task.isSuccessful()) {
...
} else {
...
}
```